# Rails - custom html data attribute for video file not recognized in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and try to use a slider that has video item in it. Below html works on local but not in production. I need to replace it with rails tag version, but I couldn't manage it.

## Works at localhost, but not at Heroku(production)

```
<div class="cd-bg-video-wrapper" data-video="/assets/video/video">
```

## I tried below line but didn't work

```
<div class="cd-bg-video-wrapper" data-video = "<% asset_path('video') %>">
```

Note: This data-video attribute's value is used by JQuery to load the video from assets.

[Path to Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ6GO.jpg)

**I also updated application.rb file as below:**

```
    require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
    require 'rails/all'
    Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
    module Europe

      class Application < Rails::Application

        config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

        config.assets.enabled = true
 config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets","slider_assets","video")
 #tried also... config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets","video")
      end

    end
```

**JQuery Function that calls the video:**

```
function uploadVideo(container) {

        container.find('.cd-bg-video-wrapper').each(function(){

            var videoWrapper = $(this);

            if( videoWrapper.is(':visible') ) {

                // if visible - we are not on a mobile device 

                var videoUrl = videoWrapper.data('video'),

                    video = $('<video loop><source src="'+videoUrl+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><source src="'+videoUrl+'.webm" type="video/webm" /></video>');

                video.appendTo(videoWrapper);

                // play video if first slide

                if(videoWrapper.parent('.cd-bg-video.selected').length > 0) video.get(0).play();

            }

        });

    }
```

I appreciate in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I was able to get this working in a Rails 5 application using the following:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.public_file_server.enabled = true

# config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "slider_assets", "videos")

# app/views/videos/index.html.erb
<%= asset_path('videos/video.mp4') %>
```

It'd be nice if the videos directory was picked up automatically, so you didn't have to explicitly say, `'videos/video.mp4'`, but I wasn't able to get that working.

Though, it's important to note that you'd need to add a data attribute for each file you're intending to use, as the files will all have MD5 fingerprints appended to their names, e.g. `video-ahutaoh687687.mp4` and `video-htutaoh23453.webm`.

Comment: I tried but didnt work. It looks like a fitting solution, but not. I provide more details by re-editing the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
<%= asset_path('video/video') %>
```

Comment: Some context around this and an explanation why this would work would be a good idea.